# Use query input for if statement condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am doing a mini-API on Express.

On an request, I want to verify that all the query parameters are filled.

Hence, my intuition led me to this:

```
app.get("/book", (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.query.seats, req.query.category, req.query.date);

    let isEmpty =
        req.query.seats === undefined ||
        req.query.category === undefined ||
        req.query.date === undefined;

    console.log(isEmpty);

    if (isEmpty === true) {
        console.log("here3");
        res.status(400).send("Missing input");
    }

    // else continue with instructions
}
```

Nevertheless, the console outputs false for isEmpty, while it tells that elements (req.query.category) is undefined, passing to the next instruction and not catching the error.

Does the elements have a different behavior in a console log and and comparison ?

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check for undefined AND empty string without problem you could do this way :

```
let isEmpty = !req.query.seats || !req.query.category || !req.query.date
```

For example :

```
var seats = '';
var category = undefined;
var date = '';


let isEmpty = !seats || !category || !date
console.log(isEmpty) // true
```

Comment: interesting, thanks! in the meanwhile I found another way: as they are inputs (process.argv) that I include in an URL constructor, I tested on "undefined" (string) and it worked.

sketchy though

Comment: glad to hear u fixed it! :)

Comment: the !variable is SO useful !! I totally forgot it existed, thanks a lot (again!) for the refresher :D